# Unix sort emits lines outside of expected order only when second column exists

Tags: sorting, unix, gnu, gnu-sort

I have a file with two columns. The first column has two underscore-separated numbers in it, and I want to sort the file lexicgraphically by this column. Now, if there is no second column, default sort does precisely what I want:

```
$ { echo 211_284; for ((i=2840;i<=2842;++i)); do echo 211_$i; done; echo 211_284; } | sort -k1
211_284
211_284
211_2840
211_2841
211_2842
```

But if I add a second column (which should be irrelevant to the sort!):

```
$ { echo 211_284 X; for ((i=2840;i<=2842;++i)); do echo 211_$i Y; done; echo 211_284 Z; } | sort -k1
211_2840 Y
211_2841 Y
211_2842 Y
211_284 X
211_284 Z
```

Or even adding a second column to just one of the rows:

```
$ { echo 211_284 X; for ((i=2840;i<=2842;++i)); do echo 211_$i; done; echo 211_284; } | sort -k1
211_284
211_2840
211_2841
211_2842
211_284 X
```

How do I sort on the first column, for real?

Comment: This is using GNU sort, not doing sorting natively in bash. Which is good -- doing sorting natively in bash is, for the greatmost part, silly -- but it means that your question is about standard UNIX tools, not about bash, and so should be tagged somewhat differently.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not familiar with the right tags to use. Threw a bunch in, feel free to edit into whatever makes sense.

Comment: I can't replicate the results.  Your second example works correctly for me using `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.23`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore anything other than the first column, use `sort -k1,1`; otherwise, you're specifying a start column but not an end column:

Also, if you don't want your locale's collation order to impact the lexographic sort relationship between digits and spaces, set `LC_ALL=C` explicitly (or, more narrowly, `LC_COLLATE=C`).

```
$ { echo 211_284 X; for ((i=2840;i<=2842;++i)); do echo 211_$i Y; done; echo 211_284 Z; } \
>   | LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1
211_284 X
211_284 Z
211_2840 Y
211_2841 Y
211_2842 Y
```

Comment: This gives the exact same output - The 211_284 rows are last instead of first.

Comment: CNR. What's your LC_COLLATE value? Your locale?

Comment: @Barry, ...I'd suggest setting `LC_ALL=C` if you want to be completely certain that localization settings play no part.

Comment: ...to be clear, that needs to be in the environment, ie. with `export`, or done on the sort command itself (`... | LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1`).

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` fixes it. Changing `-k1` to `-k1,1` is not an issue.

Comment: To be clear: Your locale determines collation order, and collation order determines (among other things) where spaces are in relation to digits in a lexographic sort.

Comment: Not *your current* issue, you mean. You indicated that you don't want the second column to be considered at all; the `1,1` is needed to prevent it from being considered if the first columns match.

Comment: Why is the space even considered if I'm sorting by the first column? Shouldn't it go from whitespace to whitespace?

Comment: @Barry, see the "extended description" section in the POSIX `sort` spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html). It's only explicit in the standard that characters used to define boundaries must not be considered part of the field when `-t` is given. In other cases, the separators *must* be part of the fields; ie: "A field comprises a maximal sequence of non-separating characters and, in the absence of option -t, any preceding field separator."

Comment: @Barry, ...that said, the behavior you observe _does_ surprise me a bit, inasmuch as -- as I read the standard -- I'd expect the spaces to be part of column two, not column one, and thus for the `-k1,1` to exclude them.

Comment: That makes [at least] two of us :)